# How do I use Balanced Payment's Address Verification Service?

Tags: balanced-payments

I've tried calling the balanced.js card.create() with an address with including one of the test postal codes or test street addresses included in the api in the function call but the object I get back does not include an avs_street_match or avs_postal_match object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/, validation of cards does not occur until an authenticated operation is performed against it. Those fields are not part of the tokenization response, but rather are part of the Card response from an authenticated operation against it. Something like a GET on the href returned in the tokenization response would provide a Card response with the fields you mention.